# スプレッドシート group by で空白セルの数もカウントしたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

```
A

B
A

B
A
```

みたいに値が入ってたり空白になってる列があって

```
 |2
A|3
B|2
```

みたいに空白を含めて値のカウントを表示したいです

`=QUERY(B2:B, "SELECT B, COUNT(B) GROUP BY B")`

みたいにかくと空のエントリはできるのにカウントは０になってしまいます
空セルをカウントする方法ってないでしょうか

Comment: 例えば、[こちら](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107305)の回答を参考にして、`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B2:B8,LEN(B2:B8)}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1"))`などはいかがでしょうか。ただし、この場合、`B2:B`を使用すると、空白行全ての行をカウントしてしまいます。これが必要なformulaかどうか不明だったため、コメントとして提案させていただきました。

Comment: できました！　ありがとうございます！　> 空白行全ての行をカウント 確かに最終行を指定しないと余分にカウントされてしまうのでそこは毎回かきかえるしかないですね

Comment: ご返事頂きありがとうございます。無事に解決したとのことで安心しました。この場合、解決した内容を回答として投稿し、アクセプトするのはいかがでしょうか。これにより、同様の問題を持っている他のユーザにも役立つと思います。

Comment: そうさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントでいただいた通り[こちら](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107305)の回答を参考にして、

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B2:B8,LEN(B2:B8)}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1"))
```

とすることで空白のカウントもできました

ただ下限行も指定しないと終わりがわからないので余分にカウントしてしまうようです